# How to post a checkbox value with database content in it? PHP&MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I got the following issue. 
I want to set a value from a database query to a checkbox value and then post the checkbox value to another file.

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kunde  WHERE UserID = $UserID";
        foreach ($db->query($sql) as $zeile)
        {                                   
                echo "<tr>";
                //echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['id']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Name']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Vorname']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Strasse']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['PLZ']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Ort']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Rufnummer']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Email']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Datum']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $zeile['Verlauf']; echo "</td>";
                echo "<form action='update.php' method='post'>";
                $id = $zeile['id'];
                echo "<td>"; echo "<label>"; echo '<input type="checkbox" name="edit" value="'; echo $id; echo '"/>'; echo "</label>"; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo "<label>"; echo '<input type="checkbox" name="delete">'; echo "</label>"; echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo "<button type='submit' class='submit'>Submit</button>"; echo "</td>";
```

Is this even possible? I also tried

`echo '<input type="checkbox" name="edit" value="'; echo $zeile['id']; echo '"/>';`

but without success. Any ideas to manage this would be great. THX

Comment: No. You'd want to have a separate `<input type='hidden'` that has that data stored in it, which you would associate with that checkbox server-side.

Comment: How can I do this? I tried, but i failed.

Comment: Just set the hidden input's `name` to something that you want to use server-side in a `POST`/`GET` variable, depending on how the form is submitting.

Comment: This works! You are the best, bro! thx alot!

Comment: Awesome, I'll set it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the value of a checkbox, but you can have a hidden input that holds a value for the checkbox.

#### HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' name='myCheckbox' />
<input type='hidden' name='myCheckbox_data' value='<?= $data ?>' />
```